# Comparing a variable with 2nd column if a file and printing the required output

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

i have a result file generated out of a query. the file has 2 columns. first is name and second is id.. Now i have an id variable. I have to compare this id variable with the values in 2nd column and print output as below.
file

```
sam,12
justin,12,
jarvis,14
```

now of the $id = 12. The output shoud be as below

```
sam is having same id as main id $id
justin is having same id as main id $id
jarvis id does not matches with main id $id
```

I tried below but is not producing the required output. can someone guide me where i am doing wrong

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} 
{ if ($2 == $id) 
echo "$1 is having same id as main id $id "
else
echo  "$1 id does not matches with main id $id" ' > a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

awk -v id=$id  -F, '
    #"id" == variable $id, "-F," == split separator
    $2==id { print $1" is having same id as main id "$2; next }
    # if second field is equals to $id; then print "...", and skip next block
    { print $1" id does not matches with main id "$2 }' input.txt > output.txt
    # else user's id is not equals to $id; print "..."
```

Output:

```
$ cat input.txt
sam,12
justin,12,
jarvis,14
$ id=12; awk -v id=$id -F, '$2==id { print $1" is having same id as main id "$2; next } { print $1" id does not matches with main id "$2 }' input.txt > output.txt
$ cat output.txt
sam is having same id as main id 12
justin is having same id as main id 12
jarvis id does not matches with main id 14
```